# Using puppet (or any thing else) instead of a bash script for an SSH based deployment

Tags: bash, puppet

I have a custom build and deployment script which work over SSH and deploy to servers (on running MacOS). The bash script does a lot of simple things like copying files, backing up the old ones and applying the correct SQL scripts for a forward moving database. But there are some advanced things like starting a remote SQL upgrade procedure which can be disconnected from and once the deployment script is started again it only goes forward if the SQL script has been applied completely (in short there is some flow control happening and bash is not really ideal for such stuff)

The script is already huge and is a mess since bash is not meant for such kind of detailed logic. Can you recommend some tools, libraries which would make things easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you tell us, I think you need a deployment tool, rather than a configuration management tool. 
To simplify, I'll distinguish the two like this:

- A **deployment tool** is a 'push' tool: When you press the button, the required actions are run to make the deployment. It's a one-step process (it can have multiple actions, but it's launched once).
- A **configuration management tool** is usually a 'pull' tool, where your servers periodically check if their configuration is exactly as the CM server tells them to be - and apply changes, if needed. You configure your servers once, and after that the system assures that all is as it should be. It is also a great tool to easily clone systems.

For deployment tools, I personally know [Fabric](http://fabfile.org), a great Python tool. But there is also Capistrano in the Ruby world. I don't know of any others.

For CM tools, Puppet and Chef seem to be the preferred choice of people nowadays. Cfengine is an older tool, which had some problems (I don't know if that has changed).

Comment: agreed, this is definitely a step up from hacking custom bash scripts. Bash is really not a good tool for complicated deployment scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my recommendations:

- Puppet
- Chef
- cfengine

These are all free (as in beer) and allow you to do what you're wanting.  They will require you to adapt your current bash script into modules to fit their design/framework.  It's a bit of work, but in the long run it tends to be better since the frameworks take care of error checking, converging configurations and a lot of other things you'd have to manually insert into your own code were you doing this yourself.

I've also used Opsware previously for this sort of thing, but that costs a fair bit of cash and, for what you're trying to do, does not offer significantly more benefit.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases moving from a bash-script to an complete solution is not as straightforward as many cloudservices claim.

With '*dont try new things when your on a deadline*' in mind:

**it could also be a good timing to refactor your bashscripts.**

I have done automated, repeatable deployments in the past using PaaS or just using GIT/SVN hooks using deployogi (which is bash) : https://github.com/coderofsalvation/deployogi

I understand your situation, but Im not sure whether its fair to say that the bash-language implies '*a mess*' and '*complex*'.
Every language allows to **hide complexity** no?

I guess code (in whatever language) gets overly complex when time does not allow us to refactor :)

PaaS is great. But always needed? I think not.